# Windows: Ctrl + Shift + N opens Internet Explorer instead of Chrome incognito

Tags: windows, google-chrome, internet-explorer, hotkeys

I have to use Internet Explorer for work which is why I have not disabled Internet Explorer on my work computer. When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in Chrome, instead of opening a Chrome incognito window, an Internet Explorer window pops up. Can I somehow disable that such that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> will open Chrome in incognito mode (as the menu in Chrome says it does)?

On Google, I did not find anything very helpful. (I'd personally be in favor of solving the problem via the Windows registry as this would not require third-party software like AutoHotkey, but I don't know what I'd have to change here.)

I'm using Windows 10. I tried to create a copy of the Chrome shortcut, add `--incognito` to it and assign a global hotkey to it, but when trying to set that hotkey, I will also be slapped in the face by IE.

Comment: Do you use a program called ClipX or any other program that might be using that shortcut?

Comment: I do use ClipX, and removing that shortcut solved the problem. Massive thanks! Wouldn't have guessed that from the fact that IE pops up. Put this in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some progams like ClipX will "take over" shortcuts, including <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for their own purposes. You can either remove the program or right-click the icon in the tray and choose **Configure** to change the duplicate shortcut to something else.

Comment: How the hell exactly did you guess the program?

Comment: Google helped me.

Comment: "How the hell did you guess it" - same thought.